# ckeditor Imageresize is not working with django

Tags: django, ckeditor, image-resizing

I am designing my site using `Django + CKeditor`. My requirement is to reduce the image size before uploading it to the server as my images are sized **3mb  ~3000x2500 pixels**, I am trying "`imageresize`" plugin for client side image resize.

**1. In the documentation Config are given to set maxWidth, maxHeight to 800. I dont know where to set this configuration.**

**2. Also want to know if any other plugin that can work better with CKeditor for reducing the image size.**

**`My settings.py`**

```
    CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'height': 400,
    'width': 900,
'toolbar': 'full',
'extraPlugins': ','.join(['html5audio', 'imageresize','youtube','image2']),
}
}
```

Latest update I have tried "`imageresize`" with an image it is not working. still remains in original pixel.

Thanks in advance.